# What's the difference between eval and class_eval?

Tags: ruby

I understand the difference between `class_eval` and `instance_eval`. I assume that the difference between `eval` and `class_eval` is the context they are evaluated in, but what does it mean in practice?

Comment: `class_eval` is useful *outside of* class definition or reopening (via `class Foo`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `eval`, you cannot choose where to run the code, it is always in your current context. Also, it only accepts a string of code. So if you have a method definition as a string, you can only use it by `eval`ing the string in a class body.

In `module_eval/class_eval` and `instance_eval` the code can be a string or a block, and you explicitly select the receiver (respectively the module as part of some inheritance chain, or the instance itself).

Notice that `some_obj.instance_eval(&blk)` is essentially the same as `some_obj.singleton_class.class_eval(&blk)`